# SQL Server - Replace nested select count by join on same table

Tags: sql-server, join, count, nested

I have both queries below working, first one with nested select statements, second one slightly better: replaced 2 select by left join + count on different table. However for the last value ("Existing"), I can't manage to perform a join on items from items (parent - child relationship). Is there a better way to do this?

**Query 1**

```
select distinct
      i.Id
    , i.Code
    , (select count(*) from operations o where o.itemid = i.id and o.operationtypeid = 10) "Added"
    , (select count(*) from operations o where o.itemid = i.id and o.operationtypeid = 20) "Removed"
    , (select count(*) from items ic where ic.ParentItemId = i.id) - (select count(*) from operations o where o.itemid = i.id and o.operationtypeid = 20) "Existing"

from items i
```

**Query 2**

```
select distinct
      i.id
    , i.code
    , count(case when o.OperationTypeId = 10 and o.ItemId = i.Id then 1 end) Added
    , count(case when o.OperationTypeId = 20 and o.ItemId = i.Id then 1 end) Removed
    , (select count(*) from items ic where ic.ParentItemId = i.id) 
     - count(case when o.OperationTypeId = 20 and o.ItemId = i.Id then 1 end) -- this is what I would like to improve

from items i
    left join operations o on o.ItemId = i.Id

group by i.id, i.code
```

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: A guess: `count(distinct case when o.OperationTypeId = 20 and o.ItemId = i.Id then o.ItemId end)`

Answer (score 0):

Changing my original CTE-based idea - please check with your data, you might need the DISTINCT in the last count() or you might have to remove it and update the GROUP BY:

```
SELECT 
    i.id,
    i.code,
    count(CASE WHEN o.OperationTypeId = 10 AND o.ItemId = i.Id THEN 1 END) Added,
    count(CASE WHEN o.OperationTypeId = 20 AND o.ItemId = i.Id THEN 1 END) Removed,
    count(DISTINCT ic.Id) - count(CASE WHEN o.OperationTypeId = 20 AND o.ItemId = i.Id THEN 1 END) Existing
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN operations o
    ON o.ItemId = i.Id
LEFT JOIN items ic
    ON ic.ParentItemId = i.id
GROUP BY i.id,
    i.code
```

Comment: I see but you still have 2 selects. I guess there is no way to avoid this in this case, even if performance may be better with your query. Also 'HierarchyCTE.ItemsCnt' is invalid (not in aggregate or group by) but as you couldn't test that's ok. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't. You have the same issue I had, which is the counts are wrong because actual values are somehow multiplied by the number of children the item has in Items table. I really think there is no way out of this without 2 select queries :/